# Scrollable Fragments within Activity (no viewpager)

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollable

I would like to make an Android-app which has the following basic layout:

[image: App]

The activity should hold several fragments (which all have different layouts), the fragments can be accessed by either scrolling left or right (in the black bordered area in the image) or by pressing the previous/next button.

The layout of the fragments contain input fields which should be validated when either the next button is pressed, or a swipe to the right is performed. If the input field is empty, the next fragment should not be displayed.

I tried doing that using a viewpager, this only works using some workarounds which aren't pretty, so I am trying to find a different approach.

So my question is: What would be the best way to implement the functionality described above without using a viewpager? Maybe putting a gesture listener on the fragments and swiping them sort of manually?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what wrong with the ViewPager?

Comment: you can use gesture listener and replace fragment as per your need.

Comment: @Blackbelt It turns out that validation is very tricky.

Comment: @SunitKumarGupta How do you mean "replace fragments"? I would need to store the content of those fragments somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Having a wizard-style UI with the buttons is fine, and there's at least one library out there for that. I generally disagree with your approach regarding the swipe events.

> It turns out that validation is very tricky

I do not know what you mean by this.

IMHO, the simplest solution is to use a `ViewPager`, where you do not add the "Next" page until the validation criteria are met, and you remove the "Next" page if the validation criteria are then un-met (e.g., user clears the field). You will need to use a custom `PagerAdapter` for this, or perhaps [my `ArrayPagerAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager), as adding/removing pages from the stock adapters does not work all that well (though they *may* be OK for just at the one end...).

But, again, this is where I feel that your UX is not a good one. Suppose you have four total possible pages in the wizard, here named A, B, C, and D. The user starts on A, fills in your field, advances to B, fills in your field, advances to C, fills in your field, advances to D, goes back to B, and clears B's field (or otherwise invalidates it). According to your flow, the user cannot advance again to C until B's field is filled out. And from the standpoint of advancing via a "Next" button, having that be disabled until B's form validates is perfectly reasonable, and users may well have seen that behavior before (e.g., desktop OS wizards). But the user is not necessarily going to understand that the Next button and a swipe are logically the same thing, as users are used to swiping to whatever they want, once they realize that they can swipe there. Hence, if I were doing this, I'd go with a straight-up wizard UI, sans swipe events.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager loads at least two fragments, the one you're viewing and the next/previous one. So you'll never be able to do what you're willing to do in a smooth way using ViewPager.

Instead, you can use the previous and next buttons to detach current fragment and attach the new one after validating your inputs. And if you want it to look like a ViewPager, you can add slide animations to the current fragment and the new one.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, may help you

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.FormKorbanActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutBottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout_korban" >

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/kerugian_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:inputType="textLongMessage"/>
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/type_spiner_kerugian"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:entries="@array/tipe_bangunan"
                    android:gravity="right" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/delete_kerugian"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_remove"
                    android:onClick="onDelete"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onCancel"
                android:text="Batal"
                android:textColor="@color/darkDeepOrange"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onNext"
                android:text="Berikutnya" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```